# Call function in another extends class

Tags: php

**Call function in a class which extends another class.**

---

I need to call a function in my class's parent class. Here is my code:

---

```
<?php

class Parents
{

    function ParentFun()
    {
        $name = 'Hello Dear';    
    }
}

class Child extends Parents
{
    function NewTest(){
        $extendFun = new Parents;
        return $extendFun->ParentFun();
    }
}

$result = new Child;

echo $result->NewTest();
```

**Thanks In Advance..**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to achieve? You can just call the inherited function using `$this`. And you can only display anything if something is returned.

```
class Parents
{

    function ParentFun()
    {
        $name = 'Hello Dear';
        return $name;

    }

}

class Child extends Parents
{
    function NewTest(){

        return $this->ParentFun();

    }
}

$result = new Child;

echo $result->NewTest();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:-

```
class Parents
{
    function ParentFun()
    {
        return 'Hello Dear';
    }
}

class Child extends Parents
{
    function NewTest()
    {
        $extendFun = new Parents;
        return $extendFun->ParentFun();
    }
}

$result = new Child;
echo $result->NewTest();
```

Just change $name to return and thats all.....